# can we click a specific cell and perform to show/hide an image in different cell?

Tags: excel, image, click, hide, show

example A1 is listed as John Doe1, B1 is blank, when A1 is clicked, B2 should show a picture of John Doe1, if we click any blank cell, the image disappears, if A2 is clicked, Jane Doe1 shows up in B1, not B2, image will only show up always in B1.
im still learning to code, please be merciful on my baby coding skills(if you even call that much a skill).

```
If Selection.Count = 1 Then
    If Range("A:A").Value = "John Doe1" Then
        ActiveSheet.Pictures("John Doe1").Visible = True
        ActiveSheet.Pictures("John Doe2").Visible = False
        ActiveSheet.Pictures("John Doe2").Visible = False
        ActiveSheet.Pictures("Jane Doe1").Visible = False
        ActiveSheet.Pictures("Jane Doe2").Visible = False
        ActiveSheet.Pictures("Jane Doe3").Visible = False
    Else if Range("A:A").Value = "John Doe2" Then
        ActiveSheet.Pictures("John Doe1").Visible = False
        ActiveSheet.Pictures("John Doe2").Visible = True
        ActiveSheet.Pictures("John Doe2").Visible = False
        ActiveSheet.Pictures("Jane Doe1").Visible = False
        ActiveSheet.Pictures("Jane Doe2").Visible = False
        ActiveSheet.Pictures("Jane Doe3").Visible = False
    End If
End If
```

Answer (score 2):

Not a bad first attempt! What you need here is a `Worksheet_SelectionChange()` event - this gets placed in the `Sheet` module (not in `Module1`).

Here's a minimal example of how this would work:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

    If Target.Value = "John Doe1" Then
        ActiveSheet.Pictures("John Doe1").Visible = True
        ActiveSheet.Pictures("John Doe2").Visible = False
        ActiveSheet.Pictures("John Doe3").Visible = False
    ElseIf Target.Value = "John Doe2" Then
        ActiveSheet.Pictures("John Doe1").Visible = False
        ActiveSheet.Pictures("John Doe2").Visible = True
        ActiveSheet.Pictures("John Doe3").Visible = False
    ElseIf Target.Value = "John Doe3" Then
        ActiveSheet.Pictures("John Doe1").Visible = False
        ActiveSheet.Pictures("John Doe2").Visible = False
        ActiveSheet.Pictures("John Doe3").Visible = True
    Else
        ActiveSheet.Pictures("John Doe1").Visible = False
        ActiveSheet.Pictures("John Doe2").Visible = False
        ActiveSheet.Pictures("John Doe3").Visible = False
    End If

End Sub
```

Alternative solution by @ScottCraner:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    ActiveSheet.Pictures("John Doe1").Visible = Target.Value = "John Doe1"
    ActiveSheet.Pictures("John Doe2").Visible = Target.Value = "John Doe2"
    ActiveSheet.Pictures("John Doe3").Visible = Target.Value = "John Doe3"
End Sub
```